# unsigned char* image to Python

Tags: python, c++, python-imaging-library, unsigned-char, pep3118

I was able to generate python bindings for a camera library using SWIG and I am able to capture and save image using the library's inbuilt functions. 
I am trying to obtain data from the camera into Python Image Library format, the library provides functions to return camera data as unsigned char* . 
Does anyone know how to convert unsigned char* image data into some data format that I can use in Python?
Basically am trying to convert unsigned char* image data to Python Image Library format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Guys, so finally after a long fight (maybe because am a newbie in python), I solved it.

I wrote a data structure that could be understood by python and converted the unsigned char* image to that structure. After writing the interface for the custom data structure, I was able to get the image into Python Image Library image format.
I wanted to paste the code here but it wont allow more tha 500 chars.
Here's a link to my code

http://www.optionsbender.com/technologybending/python/unsignedcharimagedatatopilimage

I've also attached files so that you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the `fromstring` method, as described here:

[How to read a raw image using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil)

Also, there's a good article on capturing data from the camera using python and opencv which is worth reading: http://www.jperla.com/blog/post/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux

Comment: well. the camera is a 1394 camera and I dont think I would be able to obtain images using OpenCV. 
In the fromstring example, python is loading from a file into a binary format which is straightforward.
In my case I have a custom structure from the 1394library that contains the image and the only way to access the data is through unsigned char*. I just got some ideas on using OpenCV for bypassing the pointer mechanism, i'll try and keep posted

Comment: How about the frombuffer method?

Comment: Here's my Code

FC2=__import__('FC2Py')

fch  = FC2.FCHelper()

pycam  = FC2.FC2PyCamera()

retval = pycam.setCamera(fch.connectCamera(7150499))

err  = pycam.StartCapture()

img  = FC2.Image()

err  = pycam.cam.RetrieveBuffer(img)


from PIL import Image

pilimg = Image.frombuffer("L",(img.GetCols(),img.GetRows()),img.GetData(),'raw', "L", 0, 1)

Comment: ERROR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1853, in frombuffer
 core.map_buffer(data, size, decoder_name, None, 0, args)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Hey KarlPhillip,
I finally undestood that inorder for python to understand the datatype unsigned char* image, I need to typemap it using a custom data structure. Once I got that I was able to get binary data and then I used the Image.frombuffer as you suggested.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume those `unsigned char`s are the actual image bytes, so you could store those directly via:

```
with open('filename', mode='wb') as file:
    file.write(image_bytes)
```

(As long as you already have a file named `filename` in the current working directory.)