# how to convert raw images to png in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-2.7

I have a folder containing over 200 `raw` images, i want to convert all of them to `png` or any other format, In C it's pretty easy but in python i don't know how it's done

I found this snippet

```
#import struct
import numpy, array, PIL, Image
from struct import *

#declarations
arr1D   =   array.array('H') #H is unsigned short

#------------------------------------
#read 16 bit unsigned raw depth image
#------------------------------------
w           =   640
h           =   480
fid        =   open('/home/salman/salman/NiSimpleRead_salman/data/200.raw')
#fid         =   open('/home/salman/test.raw')
numBytes    =   w*h
arr1D.read(fid, numBytes)
fid.close()

#----------------------------------------------------
#convert to float numpy array -> scale -> uint8 array
#----------------------------------------------------
numarr = numpy.array(arr1D, dtype='float');
numarr = 255 - (numarr*255.0/numarr.max())
numarr.shape = (h,w)
numarr = numarr.astype('uint8')

#======================
#IMAGES
#======================

#2D numpy array -> image 
#-----------------------
img        =   Image.fromarray(numarr); #print data.dtype.name

#image view and save
#-------------------
#img.show()
img.save('/home/salman/test.png')
```

This is the only snippet that I can find, is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Alternately, use ImageMagick at the command line: `convert *.raw --format png`.

Comment: Or, alternately alternately, use the ImageMagick bindings for Python.

Comment: "In C it is pretty easy" - can you point to that?

Comment: @jsbueno, What I meant by saying *"In C it is pretty easy"* is that i saw so many snippets converting `raw` to other formats but i only saw 1 snippet in python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
rawData = open("foo.raw" 'rb').read()
imgSize = (x,y)
# Use the PIL raw decoder to read the data.
# the 'F;16' informs the raw decoder that we are reading 
# a little endian, unsigned integer 16 bit data.
img = Image.fromstring('L', imgSize, rawData, 'raw', 'F;16')
img.save("foo.png")
```

Using [the handbook](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) and [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil).

The First argument is the image mode and can be any from:

- 1 (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)
- L (8-bit pixels, black and white)
- P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a colour palette)
- RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true colour)
- RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true colour with transparency mask)
- CMYK (4x8-bit pixels, colour separation)
- YCbCr (3x8-bit pixels, colour video format)
- I (32-bit signed integer pixels)
- F (32-bit floating point pixels)

Comment: `F;16` is no longer true as an unsigned integer. I think they are now using it as float. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45445890/8055011

Comment: How to do reverse of this? I have ndarray and I want to write (.raw) format image ?

Answer (score 9):

```
from PIL import Image
rawData = open("foo.raw", 'rb').read()
imgSize = (703,1248)# the image size
img = Image.frombytes('L', imgSize, rawData)
img.save("foo.jpg")# can give any format you like .png
```

was the one that worked for me

Comment: How to do reverse of this? I have ndarray and I want to write (.raw) format image ?