# Convert heightmap grayscale 16bit .RAW file to PNG/JPEG

Tags: python, image-processing, heightmap

I have a grayscale 16bit heightmap from a game that I want to convert to PNG/JPEG using Python. Each map has 30+ heightmaps in a grid. I want to put every file in a grid then export a single file. I am able to with the minimaps which are .DDS files, now I need to do that for the heightmaps. I tried:

1. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922402/how-to-convert-raw-images-to-png-in-python):

   ```
   rawData = open("foo.raw" 'rb').read() imgSize = (x,y)
   # Use the PIL raw decoder to read the data.
   # the 'F;16' informs the raw decoder that we are reading
   # a little endian, unsigned integer 16 bit data.
   img = Image.fromstring('L', imgSize, rawData, 'raw', 'F;16') img.save("foo.png")
   ```

   `Image.fromstring()` says `fromstring` doesn't exist.
2. RawPy:

   ```
   import rawpy
   import imageio

   path = 'image.raw'
   with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
       rgb = raw.postprocess()
   imageio.imsave('default.tiff', rgb)
   ```

   RawPy isn't able to read the file saying it is a raw file.
3. OpenCV:

   ```
   import cv2
   import numpy as np
   from PIL import Image
   import torchvision

   with open('height.raw', 'rb') as infile:
        buf = infile.read()

   x = np.fromstring(buf, dtype='uint8')

   img = cv2.imdecode(x, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

   image = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage(img)
   image = Image.open(image)
   image.show()
   ```

   Can't make it show/export the image even if OpenCV is able to open it.
4. I can open the heightmap in Photoshop by importing as 131x131 16 bit PC IBM. But this needs to be automated since there are 30+ files per map and over 20 maps.
5. [rawpixels.net](https://rawpixels.net/) can load the heightmap by changing some settings:

   ```
   width: 131
   height: 131
   offset: 1
   Predefined Format: Grayscale 8bit
   bpp1: 16
   ```

   It uses JavaScript. Converting to Python isn't easy. I tried Js2Py to run (no luck), convert the JavaScript to Python (also no luck).

Maybe I can save the page, edit the settings as I want, in Python load the map file and use Js2Py searching for resulting div image, but that seems complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

width = 131
height = 131

with open("height.Raw", "rb") as rawimg:
   img = np.fromfile(rawimg, np.dtype('u2'), width * height).reshape(height, width)
   colimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
   cv2.imwrite("test.png", colimg)
```

Got it to work using [this](https://www.pythonfixing.com/2022/01/fixed-reading-and-saving-12bit-raw.html).