# having cv2.imread reading images from file objects or memory-stream-like data (here non-extracted tar)

Tags: python, performance, opencv, tar, imread

I have a `.tar` file containing several hundreds of pictures (`.png`). I need to process them via opencv.

I am wondering whether - for efficiency reasons - it is possible to process them without passing by the disc. In other, words I want to read the pictures from the memory stream related to the tar file.

Consider for instance

```
 import tarfile
 import cv2

 tar0 = tarfile.open('mytar.tar')
 im = cv2.imread( tar0.extractfile('fname.png').read() )
```

The last line doesn't work as `imread` expects a file name rather than a stream.

Consider that this way of reading directly from the `tar` stream can be achieved e.g. for text (see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8858414/1714661)).

---

Any suggestion to open the stream with the correct `png` encoding?

Untarring to ramdisk is of course an option, although I was looking for something more *cachable*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @abarry and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547525/1714661) I managed to find the answer.

Consider the following

```
def get_np_array_from_tar_object(tar_extractfl):
     '''converts a buffer from a tar file in np.array'''
     return np.asarray(
        bytearray(tar_extractfl.read())
        , dtype=np.uint8)

tar0 = tarfile.open('mytar.tar')

im0 = cv2.imdecode(
        get_np_array_from_tar_object(tar0.extractfile('fname.png'))
        , 0 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps use [imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imdecode#cv2.imdecode) with a buffer coming out of the tar file?  I haven't tried it but seems promising.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely the right hint. Please see my answer below.