# python cv2 read video from archive

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, tar

I have a `.tar` file containing a `.mp4` video. I need to open them via OpenCV (v2.4.8) in PyQt4 without extracting the archive to the file system.

Here there solution for [reading images from tar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186591/having-cv2-imread-reading-images-from-file-objects-or-memory-stream-like-data-h)

Instance:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tarfile

tar0 = tarfile.open('files.tar')
fileg = tar0.extractfile('1.mp4')#  (may be convert fileg to VideoCapture?)
```

Comment: What is the wrong with the solution in that link?

Comment: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198846/5781248) seems applicable.

Comment: The solution in the link is correct, but cv2.imdecode method is not usable for a video file.