# upload a file to tmp folder flask python

Tags: python, image, video, flask, gif

I am trying to extract frames from gifs/videos that have been uploaded to the server through a post request. I have the code working to grab the file:

```
my_file = request.files['file']
```

however if that file is a gif or video I'm kind of stuck. The cv2 and Image package both require that the video or gif is stored in a file and you input the filename to grab the file, but that's not going to be possible as I'm not trying to store user data. So what I want to do is uppload it to a tmp folder, extract the frames then put it back, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: This question is current closed as a duplicate of a deleted question, so I cannot post a proper answer, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552926/how-to-read-raw-png-from-an-array-in-python-opencv it seems that at least cv2 can be made to read an image directly from an in-memory stream by first converting it into a numpy array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_file.save("path/to/your/tmp/folder")
```

saves the uploaded file there.

Comment: any idea on how I could delete it afterwards? theres a privacy concern with storing it

Comment: `import os` and `os.remove("path/to/tmp/file")` removes it.