# read and display raw image using python

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to try view the image using spyder python as in:

[skydrive share](http://sdrv.ms/15JHr6a)
the image is:

- uint16 (10-bit)
- width:1376 pixel, height: 960 pixel
- no header
- bayer pattern blue-green, green-red

What python script is suitable?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a try on this first and post the code snippet or error if you are facing some issue

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil)

Comment: also note that this is about "image processing" not about the "processing" programming language.

Comment: You could split this into 3 or 4 steps and each would be a question on its own. 1) How to read the image. 2) Bayer demosaicing. 3) Converting from a linear colorspace to something gamma corrected such as sRGB. 4) Applying white balance or color correction.

Comment: this is what I get from [link]http://www.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/?id=227

<!-- language: lang-none -->
fin = open('001.raw', 'rb')
s = fin.read()
fin.close()
arr = array.array('H', s)
arr.byteswap()
img = numpy.array(arr, dtype='uint16').reshape(960,1376)
imshow(img, gray());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

Start with imports

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Now allocate the space

```
image = np.empty((1376,960), np.uint16)
```

Read the image into your array:

```
image.data[:] = open('20_1-20ms.raw').read()
```

Display it:

```
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't work on color data (i.e., a stack of 3 images, one for each color).  Matplotlib's imshow requires either floats or int8s to produce a reasonable RGB image.  Attempting to call it with int16s will produce garbled noise.  You must either bitshift your 10 bit data to 8 bit data, or convert to float e.g., im_float = im_int / (2**10 - 1.).

Comment: I tried this out to read a .raw file but I'm getting this error: NotImplementedError: memoryview slice assignments are currently restricted to ndim = 1.