# Python/Numpy — NotImplementedError: memoryview slice assignments are currently restricted to ndim = 1

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to read a file and save to a numpy matrix to display it, but I'm stuck on an error.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = np.empty((1664, 512, 256), np.uint16)

reader = open('Datasets/burned_wood_with_tape_1664x512x256_12bit.raw', "rb").read()

image.data[:] = reader

plt.imshow(image)
```

And this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH]", line 8, in <module>
    image.data[:] = reader
NotImplementedError: memoryview slice assignments are currently restricted to ndim = 1
```

Any ideas of what's causing this error?

Edit:

I am using this SO question to write my program: [read and display raw image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069028/read-and-display-raw-image-using-python)

Comment: Did you try `image[:]`, because `image.data[:]` will return a pointer to the memory. I am assuming you will have to assign the value directly.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a value to `image.data`?  Who or what suggested that?  The `data` attribute of an array is a low level object that only the most advanced `numpy` programmers are allowed to touch :)

Comment: @AnuragReddy This just returns "Memory Error".

Comment: @hpaulj See my edit please.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there a way to assign it directly? Like iterate through the data and assign each index.