# What format does "adb screencap /sdcard/screenshot.raw" produce? (without "-p" flag)

Tags: android, python, adb, python-imaging-library

I am looking to use `adb screencap` utility without the `-p` flag. I imagined output will be dumped in raw format, but doesn't look like it. My attempts of opening the raw image file with `Pillow` (python) library resulted in:

```
$ adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.raw screenshot.raw
$ python
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.open('screenshot.raw')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/....../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2025, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Found out not the right way to read raw images like this, I even gave the following a shot: [How to read a raw image using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil)

```
>>> with open('screenshot.raw', 'rb') as f:
...     d = f.read()
... 
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.frombuffer('RGB', len(d), d)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: the frombuffer defaults may change in a future release; for portability, change the call to read:
  frombuffer(mode, size, data, 'raw', mode, 0, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/..../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1896, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/Users/..../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1821, in frombytes
    im = new(mode, size)
  File "/Users/..../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1787, in new
    return Image()._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not int
```

All possible mode option lead to same `TypeError` exception.

Here is what `hexdump` utility reveals:

```
$ hexdump -C img.raw | head
00000000  d0 02 00 00 00 05 00 00  01 00 00 00 1e 1e 1e ff  |................|
00000010  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  |................|
*
000038c0  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  21 21 21 ff 2b 2b 2b ff  |........!!!.+++.|
000038d0  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  |................|
*
00004400  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  47 47 47 ff 65 65 65 ff  |........GGG.eee.|
00004410  20 20 20 ff 1e 1e 1e ff  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  |   .............|
00004420  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  1e 1e 1e ff 1e 1e 1e ff  |................|
*
```

On osx:

```
$ file screenshot.raw 
screenshot.raw: data
```

`screencap` help page doesn't reveal much either about format of output data without `-p` flag:

```
$ adb shell screencap -h
usage: screencap [-hp] [FILENAME]
   -h: this message
   -p: save the file as a png.
If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.
If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.
```

Comment: As I guess your on a linux workstation, Did you try to use the command "file" , it may help you to give some clues on the file type/format. but with "raw" , means minimal format type (no special header for identification)

Comment: yes, output updated above.

Comment: for what is responsabile -p flag? I used it with -p and without, it seems that output is equal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the extract of your file , I guess your raw file is formated as
width x height then the whole set of RGBA pixels (32 bits) (width x height times)
Here I see you get a 720x1280 image captured..

May the ImageMagick toolset help you to view/convert it in a more appropriate file format.
Here below a sample that may help you
(ImageMagick convert command, for osx see http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ )

```
# skip header info  
dd if=screenshot.raw of=screenshot.rgba skip=12 bs=1
# convert rgba to png
convert -size 720x1280 -depth 8 screenshot.rgba screenshot.png
```

If it doesn't work you may try changing skip=12 by skip=8 and/or 720x1280 by 1280x720 ..

Hope that help

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Just to add, I runned into https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/db71718554b2a98c5d7ead3899e9be1a4fb454a0/tools/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/MonkeyRunner.java and getDeviceImage code block does helps with the format hint too.

Answer (score 19):

Format:

- 4 bytes as uint32 - `width`
- 4 bytes as uint32 - `height`
- 4 bytes as uint32 - [`pixel format`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html)
- (`width` * `heigth` * `bytespp`) bytes as byte array - `image data`, where `bytespp` is bytes per pixels and depend on `pixel format`. Usually `bytespp` is 4.

Info from [source code of screencap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.3/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp).

For your example:

```
00000000  d0 02 00 00 00 05 00 00  01 00 00 00 1e 1e 1e ff
```

- `d0 02 00 00` - width - uint32 0x000002d0 = 720
- `00 05 00 00` - height - uint32 0x00000500 = 1280
- `01 00 00 00` - pixel format - uint32 0x00000001 = 1 = `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` => `bytespp = 4` => RGBA
- `1e 1e 1e ff` - first pixel data - `R = 0x1e; G = 0x1e; B = 0x1e; A = 0xff;`

Pixels with data stored in array of bytes with size 720*1280*4.

Answer (score 4):

To read adb screencap raw format in python:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (1920, 1080), raw[12:], 'raw', 'RGBX', 0, 1)
```

The most important part is skipping the header, as mentioned in @Emmanuel's answer

Note that (1920, 1080) are your device resolution which can be obtained with

```
adb shell wm size
```

Hopefully this will save someone 12 hours investigating why cv2.matchTemplate has different match on almost identical images.