# Pillow : How to get Image Object from a raw file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How can I get a raw file into an Image Object of Pillow python library ?

when i try the following code :

```
path = '/Users/me/Desktop/SonyRX100III_raw.ARW'
img = Image.open(path)
```

I get this error

```
OSError: cannot identify image file '/Users/me/Desktop/SonyRX100III_raw.ARW'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a raw image using PIL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil)

Comment: no,
the methode fromstring() is deprecated, also i don't wana care about the mode of photo or the size before getting the Image Object